# Log mysql queries using PHP without a DB wrapper

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, logging, mysqli

In my case Mysqli php extension is used to access mysql server.
It is a WordPress site, but many plugins recently switching from using [`wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) wrapper because other plugins are trying to manipulate the queries via hooks.

I need to log the queries for selected users. I believe that can be achieved only by filtering and logging the queries using php.

Before or after calling [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is it possible to get the query in php?

P.S: I am looking for universal solution, so I can implement it in my plugin.

Comment: MySQL provide log all general queries, just set `general_log = 1` and `general_log_file = absolute/path/file.log` under `mysqld` section in my.ini

Comment: You can extend the `mysqli` class and overload the `mysqli_query()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not possible with raw PHP.

You can always write a db wrapper of your own and use it in your plugin though. You are even encouraged to do so, as raw mysqli, being a thin wrapper over Mysql C API, is almost unusable as is and must be wrapped in a helper library anyway.

Comment: Not possible to use the wrapper here. I need to track other plugins query.